Error en código de salida del programa en ensamblador
Estoy usando ensamblador, pero en una página web que no es muy descriptiva con los errores.
No sé cual es el error en mi código, solo sé que lo provoca la última línea de código.
section .data
    msg db "Hola Mundo", 0b00001010, 0b00001101 ; Relativa equivalencia a una variable
    len equ $ - msg ; Longitud de mi supuesta variable
    
section .text
    global _start
    
_start:
  mov eax, 0b00000100 ; llama al sistema de impresión de datos
  mov ebx, 0b00000001 ; indica al sistema que quiero imprimir algo
  mov ecx, msg ; indica lo que quiero imprimir
  mov edx, len ; indica el tamaño o largo de lo que quiero imprimir
  int 0b10000000 ; llamada al sistema de interrupciones
  mov eax, 0b00000001 ; indica que quiero salir del programa
  int 0b10000000 ; Ayuda a indicar una salida del programa


Parece estar bien, lo unico que te falta es hacer que ebx sea cero antes de hacer el ultimo syscall para que el código de error sea cero (indica "éxito" en linux). Mira la tabla de syscalls

Gracias, apenas hay tutoriales en línea de ensamblador y se me está dificultando el aprendizaje.

En mi carrera eliminaron el aprendizaje de ensamblador, pero yo quería aprenderlo porque me interesa optimizar código C++, pero hay muchas cosas que no entiendo y ahora que estoy aprendiendo ensamblador me doy cuenta del porque. Gracias por la ayuda.

¿Cómo marco la pregunta cómo respondida?
